# How do I reduce the number of Xero api calls below the 5000/day limit?

Tags: xero-api

I have a xero tenant with 6000 clients; how do I get all the custom fields for all the clients without going over the 5000 api call limit? See  https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/limits

The original api calls are for the WorkflowMAX api:

- staff.api/list
- client.api/list?detailed=true
- client.api/get/nnnn/customfield where nnnn is the client id from the previous api call.

We have had this working without problems using the standard WorkflowMAX urls, as we respected the 30 second delay before retrying the rate limited request.

Comment: How often do you need to request _all_ the custom fields for _all_ the clients? Does Workflow have the "webhook" option? I wondered whether you could get the information over a period of time, and have it call a webhook when anything changes.

Comment: The problem with web hook or the last modified filter option is that not all changes trigger  or set the last modified time.  It is the staff member of the tenant that determines when the request is done & they expect it to be completed within 4 hours. At the moment for the large tenants it takes about 2.5 hours

Comment: The problem with the modified time not being updated has existed since July 2014.  ie You can make changes to items attached to only 1 client & you cannot see the changes if you filter by the modified time.